# How do I lock one cell without locking sheet? I have two signatures that need to happen at different times

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet that has to be signed off on twice and neither reviewer can have the password. I can get the the whole worksheet to lock after the first signature but then the second person can't sign. I'd like to lock cell range F2:K2 after the first signature and move my worksheet locking script to look for changes to the second signature. I've tried at least 6 approaches and no luck. It keeps wanting to lock the entire sheet. Two ranges: F2:K2 and N2:O2. First user saves the doc with a new name and then second reviewer opens it and signs off in N2:O2

code for first sig F2:K2 that locks everything. I need this cell to lock when saved and leave the worksheet unlocked until the second reviewer signs off. Help!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Intersect(Range("F2:M2"), Target)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"
xRg.Locked = True
Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="PASSWORD"
End Sub
```

Comment: Cells are "Locked" and worksheets are "Protected" - it's less confusing to stick to those terms.  Is the person performing the "signing" entering data into multiple cells?  Your code would lock the range after a single entry.

Comment: From what you're saying it seems like the code should go in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. You can then check if the first sig has been signed. If so, lock it and unlock the second sig and protect the sheet before saving. If the second sig has been signed then lock those cells and protect the sheet.

Comment: Can you lock a cell without "protecting" the entire worksheet after the person types in their name? The two people signing do not change any data. They just approve of what's there. So the first person signs and it locks everything including the second signing field. The password can not be given out to either people. How would I pull this off in the workbook_before_save? It still all comes down to locking a specific cell while the rest of the worksheet has unlocked cells, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that by default any Excel cell is locked when you protect a worksheet. Therefore you need to unlock the desired cells if they are not signed already.

Also I would use the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event for this task.

Below is an example for a worksheet called `Sheet1`. This will run whenever the worksheet is saved.

So lets assume …

1. … the workbook is saved but no one signed:
   » All cells are locked (by default) except F2:K2 and N2:O2 (these ar unlocked and can be signed).
2. … the workbook is saved and 1. person signed in F2:
   » All cells are locked except N2:O2
3. … the workbook is saved and 2. person signed in N2:
   » All cells are locked.

See the example below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Unprotect Password:="1234"

    If ws.Range("F2") <> vbNullString Then 'check if F2 is signed
        ws.Range("F2:K2").Locked = True
    Else
        ws.Range("F2:K2").Locked = False
    End If

    If ws.Range("N2") <> vbNullString Then 'check if N2 is signed
        ws.Range("N2:O2").Locked = True
    Else
        ws.Range("N2:O2").Locked = False
    End If

    ws.protect Password:="1234"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you supplied (THANK YOU!) but it is not working. All cells are "locked" except the two sig fields (F2:K2 and N2:O2). I named the active worksheet as "Sheet1" to match your code and entered the code in the Sheet1 section of the VBAProject (not ThisWorkbook). No errors but does not protect the cells. I save, close, and reopen - sig fields editable. Review tab I can still "protect sheet" and "protect workbook" so WB is not Locked. Saved as xlsm file using Excel 2016 w Macros enabled. Am I missing something? I'm sure that I am. I tried to follow your exact scenerio. @Peh

Comment: @JimFrancis `Workbook_BeforeSave` must be in `ThisWorkbook` (see the beginning `Workbook_`). A worksheet does not have a `_BeforeSave` event (because you can save a workbook but not a single worksheet).

Comment: it worked PERFECTLY - I can't thank you enough. Seriously!